# Bit-level endianness

Tags: c++, windows, x86, cpu-architecture

How to check the 'endianness' of OS at bit-level or Does an OS even care in what order the bits are stored?

Comment: "Does an OS even care how bits are stored?" Er, yes!

Comment: Specifically, the OS might know/care at some levels of abstraction, but the level of abstraction provided by the C++ programming language doesn't.

Comment: It matters in case of a compressed stream, but it's application specific, not OS or processor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char` is the smallest addressable unit of memory, so you don't care what happens beyond that level - you can't read/write less than `char` anyway, hence the idea of "endianness-at-bits-level" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since a byte (8bits) is the smallest addressable unit on any architecture I have ever heard of, the question is irrelevant. I always access the "4" bit as `1 << 2`, whether this is the 3rd or 6th transistor at the address space is irrelevant.

Byte level endianness is however important because I can set the ninth least significant bit on a big endian architecture as `*x | (1 << 9)` or `*(x+1) | 1`.